# Trouble using dicts parsed by AST

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked at all the other posts here asking the same question, but I still cannot figure out why I keep getting this Traceback. The strange thing is that the program works as intended but always brings up this Traceback at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/me/Python/NextLogAudit.py", line 5, in <module>
  i = ast.literal_eval(i)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
  node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
  return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
File "<unknown>", line 1

^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of this error so the program can exit cleanly. Also, it won't allow me to put 2 conditions in my if statement regarding the dict, so I had to nest the second condition in the first if. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with how AST is parsing the dict but cannot figure it out. The file I am opening is a list of dictionaries in string format:

```
with open('/home/me/Python/logtest') as f:
for i in f.readlines():
    i = ast.literal_eval(i)
    if re.search("Preview accessed.+", i["message"]):
        if i["user"] == "user1":
            name = re.search('(?<=Preview accessed: \").+(?=\.)', \
                    i["message"])
            print("{} viewed {} on {}".format(i["user"], \
                name.group().replace('\\',''), 
                       i["time"].replace('+00:00','')))
    else:
        print("Nothing")
```

Comment: can we see the input data?

Comment: Already solved. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to guard against empty lines - there is one after all your data:

```
with open('/home/me/Python/logtest') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        if not i.strip():  # do nothing for empty lines
            continue
        i = ast.literal_eval(i)
        # ... rest of your code ...
```

Else it reads something that is not an dictionary after evaling it and you index into when using

```
i["message"]
```

which does not work.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. I didn't suspect blank spaces would be counted as "something". Would you mind explaining why, in this particular case, I could not put 2 conditions into my if statement, but it worked if I nested the second if? With your solution, the if clause works as expected with multiple conditions.

Comment: @zz99 `print( ast.literal_eval("") )`  gives you your exact error - there are no `if`'s executet. My code checks the content of the line _first_ and skipps it if empty. It never reaches the problematic `ast.literal_eval("")` statement.

Comment: Now I understand. The list of dicts had some whitespace at the end. That's why it "worked" and then errored out at the end. The Traceback was very cryptic in this case. Thanks for figuring it out.